# How to tell if there are unsaved changes to a file in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

When there are unsaved changes for a particular file, in some editors a * appears by the filename, or there is some other indication. In PhpStorm, is there anything to indicate unsaved changes?

I can't see any indication of the save status on screen when I make changes or save changes.

Comment: Perhaps obvious to some, but this question/answer also applies to WebStorm, at least as of version 2016.3.

Comment: @sherb They also apply to IntelliJ

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Editor -> General -> Editor Tabs -> Mark modified tabs with an asterisk

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted! Not sure why it's not enabled by default...

Comment: It's not enabled by default because the WebStorm team (Jetbrains) is [incredibly stubborn about forcing autosave on](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-98513) even when it [conflicts with various web development frameworks like Meteor](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14045).